# How to change subdirectory to a subdomain in Apache2?

Tags: redirect, mod-rewrite, apache2

Lets assume I have a website `abc.com` with sub-directories `x`, `y` and `z`. So website urls are like,

> abc.com/x/
>
> abc.com/y/
>
> abc.com/z/

Now lets assume I have 3 sub-domains for each sub-directory like below.

> x.abc.com
>
> y.abc.com
>
> z.abc.com

Now I want to redirect requests like `abc.com/x/` to `x.abc.com`. And I have lot of directories and I cannot add rules for each directory.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [dynamically configured mass virtual hosting](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/mass.html) (of mod_vhost_alias module). You need a wildcard entry in DNS server for resolution. For www.x.com.com and content on /home/x/www :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteMap lowercase int:tolower
RewriteCond %{lowercase:%{HTTP_HOST}} ^www\.([^.]+)\.abc\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*) /home/%1/www$1
```